# Should I add slf4j dependency to implement Sentry.io or not?

Tags: android, slf4j

I'm going to implement Sentry.io Log Service in my Android App.There is a comment in it's installation guide which says:

> ```
> // this dependency is not required if you are already using your own
> // slf4j implementation
> compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
> ```

I don't know I should add this dependency or not.

Does Android use it's own slf4j implementation?

Comment: No, Android does not include an slf4j implementation out of the box.

Comment: And I'm not using my own slf4j implementation, too. so I should add this dependency. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796579/henry) said in comments, Android doesn't include an slf4j implementation, So I Should Add this dependency to get ready to setup [Sentry](https://sentry.io/).